# PHP > Unable to embed youtube video by function

Tags: class, function, youtube, embed, media

I don't know what's wrong with my embed script, to my logic it should properly embed the video in the frame, but it loads a framed view of www.youtube.com instead of my video video.

There are 2 files in a single directory:

ClassMedia.php:

```
 <?php
class Media {

    public function embedYT($code){
        echo "<iframe width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$code." frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        }}
```

Demo.php:

```
    <?php include "classMedia.php"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
$media = new Media();
 $code = "XSGBVzeBUbk";
$media-> embedYT($code);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a single quote right after `src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$code."`, you want this:

```
echo "<iframe width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$code."' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

Note the added single quote.

YouTube ends up seeing a bad URL (`http://www.youtube.com/embed/$code frameborder=` where `$code` is the real code) and hands you the homepage instead of what you think you were asking for.